# Using fsolve from scipy.optimize on arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to solve an equation system with python's fsolve. I want to pass a 2-dimensional array to a function and then return a combination of the columns. The function seems to work but I keep getting the error 'IndexError: too many indices for array'. I don't see what I'm doing wrong. If someone could help me and explain what I'm doing wrong (and what I could do instead) I would be very grateful. The code that yields the error is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

x0 =np.array([[1,0],[1,0]])

def f(x):
    x1 = x[:,0]
    x2 = x[:,1]
    return np.array([x1**2-4,x2**2-9])

fsolve(f,x0)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using arrays in the return values of `f(x)`, which takes just two variables, `x1` and `x2` (this is where the index error happens). `x` has 4 entries, so you would call it like so:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

x0 = np.array([[1,0],[1,0]])

def f(x):
    #x1 = x[:,0]
    #x2 = x[:,1]
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    return np.array([x1**2-4, x2**2-9])

#fsolve(f, x0)
print(fsolve(f, x0[:,0]))
print(fsolve(f, x0[:,1]))
```

which produces (note a possible iteration problem):

```
[2. 3.]
[0. 0.]
```

Not sure if that answers it but if you want to process the full array you will have to process it by line (or column).